# Wallet UI turns black after sending

Tags: wallet

After trying to send miotas, wallet UI becomes black and its not sending. I checked the address and no transactions is done. I have no idea what to do about it. I have the new version on wallet (2.5.6).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 open issues regarding this behavior on github :

- https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/issues/986
- https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/issues/857

So you are just hitting a bug in wallet. Best you can do is contributing to the resolution by providing precise circumstances and reproducible use case (or fixing by yourself and submitting a PR).

Comment: I dont understand any thing, how can I help myself